# Notation of a point on a plane

Tags: geometry, notation, plane-geometry

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to notate following conclusion about plane $H$ and point $A$. ($A \in H$)

> If plane $H$ is not parallel to the $yz$-plane of the coordinate system, a $A_x$ exist for every combination of $A_y$ and $A_z$

My try

$$\forall H \nparallel H_{yz}, A_x \exists \forall A_y, A_z \in \Bbb R $$

Comment: What are $A_x $ etc.? Notation is not universal. If you define it you may get an answer.

Comment: @user254665 I'd guess that $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$

Comment: @Cheese Yes indeed

Comment: Do you really need to use the $\nparallel$ symbol?

Comment: If plane $H$ is parallel with the xy-plane the theorem doesn't stand, so I guess I have to include it

Comment: Any point $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ on $H$ exists, so I do not understand the part where you say that $A_x$ exists for every combination of $A_y$ and $A_z$. It makes no sense to me since it's true for any three-dimensional point.

Comment: What I want to say is that if you can pick a random value for $A_y$ and $A_z$ you can determine the value for $A_x$ if $H$ is not parallel to the yz-plane. I did mistake myself by saying xy-plane in the question.

Comment: If $H$ is parallel to the $yz$-plane, it means that for any point $A\in H$, $A_x$ is equal to a constant $k$. So, for any "random" point on $H$ for which you know $A_y$ and $A_z$ on $H$, you will also always be able to determine the value of $A_x$ since $A_x=k$.

Comment: I know that, that's why I need a notation for the case when $H$ is not parallel to the $yz$-plane. Just ignore the case where $H$ is parallel. I'm not looking for an answer for a mathematical problem. I'm just searching for the right notation.